# Merge multiple table-like files

Tags: csv, join, awk, merge, tabular

I need to merge 6 similar tab-delimited tables with 5 columns, as shown in the example below: 
file s1

```
  s1
A 4 
B 3
C 6
D 3
```

file s2

```
  s2
A 8
B 5
E 4
F 3
G 6
```

file s3

```
  s3
A 3
B 6
C 9
E 9
F 6
G 8
H 4
```

output

```
  s1 s2 s3
A 4  8  3
B 3  5  6
C 6  -  9
D 3  -  -
E -  4  9
F -  3  6
G -  6  8
H -  -  4
```

And so on. The goal is to merge similar 'letters' in a way, that each values from different files (if they are present) are added to the appropriate columns (if not present then mark it as '-' or '0').

I've tried `join` and `awk`, but I did not succeeded and I think it requires more advanced approach.

Comment: Please show your attempts. This has been asked similarly many times

Comment: Here is a closely related question on UL: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136759/17666